# How to setup my WD EX2 NAS for remote access

Tags: networking, macos, vpn, nas, ddns

I have recently bought a WD EX2 Ultra which is working fine in my local network. Now I want to set it up for remote access, so I can access it when I am not in my local network.

There is a way to connect through My Cloud in your browser. I have checked this out but this is not giving the preferred solution. I want to be able to see the NAS in my finder (I'm using a mac, so I would be using 'connect to server').

So far (1,5 days of trying to set it up) I haven't found the best steps how to do this and getting this to work. I have tried it with Dynamic dns but was lost in what steps I would need to take after setting up a DDNS.

I also checked the option to set up a VPN (nordvpn) on the NAS, but because I am using mac it seems very difficult and impossible to do through Terminal.

Comment: You are aware that WD had a product line of NAS devices, that could be remotely wiped, when made public to the internet.

Comment: @Ramhound This regarding the WD My Book as I read it. And yes, I am looking for a secure way to connect my EX2 to the internet.

Comment: VPN would be the only safe way.  That means running a VPN service within your network on a device that supports it, connecting the NAS to that device either (directly) or connecting the NAS itself to the VPN allowing any other device to also be connected to the VPN.  At that point it should just be an accessible device on the VPN.  If that’s possible with your device I have no idea, just thought I would bring up the fact, WD literally had a product in the news that was being remotely wiped maliciously due to a security flaw in the firmware; While a different product shared code often happens

Comment: @Ramhound NordVPN has a small tutorial on how to install it on the WD NAS, problem is is that they use Bitvise in their tutorial and I can't install it on my MacOS.

Comment: There are hundreds of SSH clients that exist one of them as to support macOS.  But doesn't macOS even have a built-in SSH capability?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes MacOS have a native SSH capability, but I can't seem to load the *.ovpn file in there

Comment: In my experience ovpn files are just flat files.  You shouldn't need a VPN profile file to make a SSH connection to a device that is SSH capable (the profile files exist to make life easier but are not required to make the connection).

Comment: @Ramhound This was how they explained it on the website of NordVPN [link](https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/NAS/1133051972/How-to-set-up-Western-Digital-My-Cloud.htm) So I tried to emulate this.

Comment: When I state the solution is to use a VPN server, I meant running the VPN server within your own network, and then made accessible to devices outside of your network.  This allows devices that are only accessible within your intranet to be connected to the VPN and accessible while connected to your VPN.  I have my doubts connecting two devices to NordVPN will accomplish what you want.  *I made the same statement in my original suggestion of using a VPN by the way*

Comment: @Ramhound So you mean to connect the VPN to my router and then use VPN outside of my network to get a connection to my network?